# Materialize modal ignore trigger

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, materialize

I've got the tabel cell with a child node in it. I would like to open a modal when user clicks on the tabel cell but not on that particular child node.:

```
<td class="modal-trigger" data-target="my_modal"> Open <i class="material-icons arrow_drop_down" aria-hidden="true">arrow_drop_down</i></td>
```

```
<div class="modal" id="set_metadata">
...
</div>
```

Modal should open when user clicks wherever on td BUT not when clicked on the arrow (it is used to fold down the table rows). In the js code I tried:

```
$(elem).on("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  { do something }
});
```

but that does not prevent the modal from being open. Is there a function in materialize that tells to ignore the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Try it.

This code only responds to a click on the tag `td`:

```
$('.modal-trigger').click(function () {
    /* here's the code for the tag "td" */
}).on('click', '.material-icons.arrow_drop_down', function(){
    return false;
    console.log('this message should not be');
});
```

This code is for clicking on the `i` tag.

```
$('.material-icons.arrow_drop_down').click(function () {
    /* here's the code for the tag "i" */
});
```

Comment: It does not work. Probably because modal opening is done by materialize. I will just remove the modal-trigger class and open it with `.show()`. Thanks for your time!